# OpenSSL error when making http request in Ruby

Tags: ruby, ssl

I have a service that makes an http request and it looks like this:

```
require 'net/http'

class SenderNameService
  def get_names(id)
    domain = "http://www.somedomain.com"
    path = "/api/orchards/users/#{id}"
    url = URI.parse(domain + path)

    req = Net::HTTP::Get.new(url.to_s)
    token = generate_token
    req.add_field("Authorization", token)

    http = Net::HTTP.new(url.host, url.port)
    http.use_ssl = true
    res = http.start do |http|
      http.request(req)
    end

    if res.code == '200'
      return JSON.parse(res.body)
    else
      raise StandardError, "Request for sender names failed"
    end
  end

  private

  def generate_token
    #Some JWT token generating logic goes here.
  end
end
```

When I make a request, I get this error:

```
OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv2/v3 read server hello A: unknown protocol
from .rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/net/http.rb:933:in `connect_nonblock'
```

What is going on? What does that error mean?

**UPDATE**: The error gets fixed when I change `http` to `https`. What is going on?

Comment: Is it possible the target has an SHA1 SSL certificate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> http.use_ssl = true
> ```
>
> UPDATE: The error gets fixed when I change http to https. What is going on?

A http URL by default uses port 80 and there is usually a server which speaks HTTP only. A https URL instead uses port 443 where a server speaking HTTPS resides. But, you are trying to enforce HTTPS (i.e. TLS+HTTP) on the http port where no TLS capable server listens. This means that your client starts a TLS handshake to this server but does not get a TLS response back but instead a HTTP response. Trying to interpret the response as TLS causes the error you see, i.e. unknown protocol.

Comment: @Jwan622: your code is enforcing TLS on the HTTP port, i.e. your are trying HTTPS on the port where the server is speaking HTTP only and thus it does not work. If you change your code to use HTTPS instead you use HTTPS on a port where the server actually provides HTTPS and thus it works.

Comment: oh I see. the `use_ssl` code enforces TLS on an http port. Let me look up what `TLS` is...

Answer (score 0):

That version of Ruby uses connect_nonblock in [http.rb](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/ruby_2_3/lib/net/http.rb#L933) to make the connections, which requests a connection to a given socket. The socket must have an address and a port so probably it is failing because it is trying to connect to an https address though port 443 (**http.use_ssl=true**), so you should rather use https instead of http (requires implementation of server side SSL) or set http.use_ssl to **false**. Please refer to: http://apidock.com/ruby/Socket/connect_nonblock